# PixelFormat deprecated 1.6?

Tags: android, camera, deprecated, pixelformat

I am using Camera.Parameters.setPixelFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG) in my android 1.6 application. The documentation says this is deprecated, but the constant value is the same as the new ImageFormat...

Should I not worry about it?

Comment: Where does it say that it is deprecated?

Comment: Presumably he means the constant in android.graphics, nothing to do with the Camera: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat.html#JPEG

Comment: you are right reuben. The documentation for setPixelFormat of Camera.Parameters says it takes an int... after finding it takes a ImageFormat.*** constant i found PixelFormat.*** and made a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, when something in an API is set as deprecated, it means that it is only there for compatibility purposes with old versions, and will eventually disappear from the API for future versions of Android.

This means that you don't need to rush to fix it, but you should start worrying about it long-term, and eventually create a new portion of code to do the same task using the current supported API functions, so that when a future version of Android API arrives that does not support the deprecated methods/functions anymore, your application is already ready to work and target new and upcoming versions of the Android platform.